# What does the set {n | n is an integer and n = n + 1} represent?

Tags: terminology, computability, number-theory

I am reading Michael Sipser's book *Introduction to the Theory of Computation*, which mentions the set $$S = \{ n \mid \text{$n$ is an integer and $n = n + 1$}\}.$$ This  doesn't make any sense to me.
I would understand if $n$ were equal to infinity or something, so it probably wouldn't matter if we added $1$ to it.
Am I understanding it correctly?
Or is this just an empty set?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

But infinity isn't an integer. Since there is no integer $n$ such that $n=n+1$, you're right that the set is empty.

Answer (score -1):

This is an empty set which is usually denoted by {}. In this case, the integer *n* is equal to itself while incremented by 1 which is mathematically impossible. Thus, this is an empty set.

EX: n = 2, then n = n + 1, 2 = 2 + 1. This is impossible.

Comment: Why those downvotes ?

Comment: This is an ancient question that already had a better answer.

Comment: (downvoters please comment what in particular makes a post *not useful*.)